# How to disable or remove specific language(java) from notepad++.?

Tags: notepad++

How can I disable java or any other specific language from `notepad++`

I tried commenting and remove the lines from `langs.model.xml` file, but still, it's showing.

I don't want to see that java in my `Languages->J->java`

Help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you restart your `notepad++` after editing `langs.model.xml` ? Did you consider some alternative [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) such as  [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)? What is your operating system, your `notepad++` version?

Comment: I did but still, it's showing. Windows 10 +Notepad++ 7.5.7, i like notepad++ because its light weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it in settings it self. 
sometimes I should stop thinking like a developer :p

[image]

[image]